# Users are unable to download my app from play store

Tags: android

I am in a strange situation. I have put an update for my app last night. After the update, users are unable to download my app. When I tried to download from my test devices (Samsung S Advance & ASUS Transformer Tablet) i am getting the error "App could not be downloaded due to an error (497)". I have attached the screen shot of the same. Kindly let me know if any of you faced this issue and know the possible resolution.

Thanks,
Nagraj

[image]

Comment: chances are this is not a problem you can solve and is a google problem

Comment: Dear Folks 

This issue has been automatically resolved after putting a subsequent update on the play store last night. I am not sure why there was an issue with that one particular update (previous one).

Thanks
Nagaraj

Answer (score 2):

It appears it may have something to do with the new Play Store update

http://www.droid-life.com/2013/08/08/play-store-update-to-4-3-10-causing-package-file-is-invalid-error-for-many-during-app-updates/

so its nothing you can do

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this several times with my own and other developers apps. There is nothing you can do and it is an issue that Google needs to resolve. Give it a couple of hours (probably fixed in less) and it should be working again

Comment: Dear Folks 

This issue has been automatically resolved after putting a subsequent update on the play store last night. I am not sure why there was an issue with that one particular update (previous one).

Thanks
Nagaraj

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem alot in recent days. Here is a good analysis of Google's Problem :

http://cafbit.com/entry/android_package_file_is_invalid[Package File Is Invalid](http://cafbit.com/entry/android_package_file_is_invalid)